# Repeater inside datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datalist

Coding platform: ASP.NET C#

I have a Repeater control inside a Datalist control.
I need to hide (Visible="false") the Datalist, if there are no records in the Repeater

I am binding the repeater like this

```
DataListItemCollection Items = ddlmain.Items;
for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
{
    //binding here
    if (Repeater.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        datalist.visible = false;
        updatepanel.update();
    }
}
```

But here i cannot hide the current row of Datalist if there are no records in the Repeater(child)

Note:All my controls are inside an UpdatePanel with UpdateMode="Conditional"

How do I correctly set `visible=false` for items that have no record in the repeater?

Comment: want to visible false of datalist if there is no record in Repeater

Answer (score 0):

So how many items will your datalist have? Only one? Your question really needs more clarification but still I will shoot blindly.

What you can do is set a public boolean variable and set it to true or false depending on your repeater count.

Then use Datalist's DataBound event or PreRender and set:

DataList1.Visible= thatpublicvariable

Comment: please show us your complete HTMLmarkup too! Incomplete Information!